# How can I use a firebase custom authentication token to query firestore using asp.net core?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have implemented a custom authentication route in an asp.net core web application to create and verify a custom token.  While I'm able to create the custom token, I'm uncertain how to use that token in Firestore, all my attempts lead to improper permissions from Firestore.

If I use the the `rules playground` in firestore with a decoded JWT against my rules I can successfully read the document with the custom claim, and if I munge the custom claim in the rules playground I fail to read the document.

Through the firestore api playground I can also make the call, but my rules are ignored entirely in this scenario.

**Firebase Auth**

```cs
public class FirebaseAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public FirebaseAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, FirebaseSettings settings)
    {
        if (FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance == null)
        {
            _ = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(settings.ServicePrinciaplJson),
                ServiceAccountId = settings.ServiceAccountId,
                ProjectId = setting.ProjectId
            });
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateToken(string id)
{
    var token = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateCustomTokenAsync(id,
        new Dictionary<string, object> {{"documentId", id}});

    var response = await VerifyAccessTokenWithAuthority(token);

    return Ok(response);
}

private async Task<CustomTokenResponse> VerifyAccessTokenWithAuthority(string accessCode)
{
    CustomTokenRequest requestBody = new() {Token = accessCode};
    
    using HttpClient client = new();

    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new(HttpMethod.Post, _settings.Authority)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestBody,
                new JsonSerializerOptions {PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase}), Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json")
    };

    var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

    var token = await response.Content.ReadAs<CustomTokenResponse>(new JsonSerializerOptions
        {PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase});

    return token;
}
```

**Firestore Request (Different asp.net core client application)**

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPassenger(string passengerId)
{
    var token = await _authorizationClient.AuthorizePassenger(passengerId);

    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
        $"https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{_firebaseAuthSettings.ProjectId}/databases/(default)/documents/myCollection/{id}/?key={_firebaseAuthSettings.ApiKey}");

    message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.IdToken);

    var response = await client.SendAsync(message);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult((int) response.StatusCode);
    }

    var docs = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Ok(docs);
}
```

**Firestore Rules**

```json
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /myCollection/{documentId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.documentId == documentId
        allow write: if request.auth.documentId == documentId
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My ruleset was off, and should have been

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /myCollection/{documentId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.token.documentId == documentId
        allow write: if request.auth.token.documentId == documentId
    }
  }
}
```